# Google map Draggable PolyLines

Tags: google-maps, jquery-mobile, google-polyline

I am having a map with some polylines with the distance [api v3]. I want that when someone drag the polyline at the same time the distance also get updated but dont know how to do. Please help me, any good tutorial or another threads are most welcome

Thanks for helping me

Naveen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a attribute which makes your polyline editable.

```
polyPath.setEditable(true);
```

Now use a listener to check the editing.

```
   google.maps.event.addListener(polyPath, 'capturing_changed', function() {

    var array = polyPath.getPath(); //getPath() gives u array of current markers latlng over map 

                    var tempDistance = 0;

                    var tempPathArray = [];

                     for(i = 0; i < array.length; i++){

                       tempPathArray.push(array.getAt(i));

                      }


                       for(k = 1; k < tempPathArray.length; k++)

                       {


  var calculateNewDistance=google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(tempPathArray[k-1],tempPathArray[k]);

                            tempDistance += calculateNewDistance;

                        }
   }
```

// make sure to add the following script to compute the distance between two latlngs

Answer (score 1):

This page describes using draggable markers and updating the distance when a marker is moved.

http://exploregooglemaps.blogspot.com.br/2012/02/measuring-distance-with-markers.html